# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined for datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I have the following codes for my table `class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable datatable"` I would like to use the datatable functionality like the searching, paging etc. Thus I added the datatable in the class list.

I have also included a link to the `<script src='js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>`
But I get this error. Which class name its missing how to add that ?
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined and it points` to this lines in the .js file.

```
(n.className+=" "+m.sClass),k?d._anHidden[g]=null:(d._anHidden[g]=n,n.parentNode.removeChild(n)),m.fnCreatedCell&&m.fnCreatedCell.call(a.oInstance,n,w(a,b,g,"display"),d._aData,b,g)}}if(0!==a.aoRowCreatedCallback.length){b=0;for(c=a.aoData.length;b<c;b++)d=a.aoData[b],C(a,"aoRowCreatedCallback",null,[d.nTr,d._aData,b])}}function K(a,b){return b._DT_RowIndex!==n?b._DT_RowIndex:null}function da(a,b,c){for(var b=L(a,b),d=0,a=a.aoColumns.length;d<a;d++)if(b[d]===c)return d;
```

Currently this how my table structure looks like

```
<div class="box-content">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable datatable" style='table-layout: fixed;'>
                          <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th style='width: 10%;'>No.</th>
                                  <th style='width: 35%;'>Name</th> 
                                  <th style='width: 25%;'>Contact Number</th>                                
                                  <th style='width: 20%;'>Stats</th>
                              </tr>
                          </thead>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure the page is loaded with the given classname prior to this script being executed?  In other words, try putting this script at the bottom of the page to verify that it's not loading before the DOM does.

Comment: I dont get you classname prior to this script being executed? Yes the javascript it ad the bottom of the page towards the end is where I call it.

Comment: Can you update your question with the table structure in your html and how you are executing the javascript for datatable?

Comment: Hi I have update my question with the table structure in my html. Is this correct?

Comment: you have a closing </table> tag right? also I'm assuming you are using this plugin? https://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Yes I have closing table and below is long php codes that is why I omitted it. Currently I run below a select query and populate my tables manually. Yes I am trying to use datatables.net

Comment: Any idea what could be my mistake?

Comment: it's hard to tell, something is calling (n.className+=" "+m.sClass) but whatever or however it was called is unclear based on what you've provided.  You may want to try and use an unminified version of the code which may provide a better idea of what your problem is.   It seems some sort of code which works with this library is being executed, but what you've provided doesn't show that.

Comment: I upgraded it to the latest version of datatable js its working now quite weird